# Defining constants in express.js

Tags: javascript, express

I want to declare a key value objects in constant file and then import them. So, this is what I wrote:

```
let ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES = 
    [
        'eng' : {'wahid'},
    ];

export default {
    ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES : ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES
}
```

I am importing it: `import common_constants from '../common_constants';`
and using as follows:

```
console.log(common_constants.ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES);
```

But the declaration of `ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES`gives me error like:

```
Unexpected token, expected : (3:18)
  1 | let ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES = 
  2 |   [
> 3 |       'eng' : {'wahid'},
    |                       ^
  4 |   ];
```

I want to make it object not array. Why I am getting the issue?

Comment: You need to swap array symbols (`[ ]`) with object symbols (`{ }`) and vice versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem lies here: `'eng' : {'wahid'}`. In javascript `{}` is called an object literal. So, an object by definition should have a key and value. Also, `Array` will not have key and pair, which you are doing in your example. You can do it like below:

```
let ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES = 
    [
        { 'eng': 'wahid'},
    ];

export default {
    ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES: ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES
}
```

Now, ACCEPTABLE_LANGUAGES is array of object.